# Use of & in declaring pointers to array

Tags: c, pointers

To make a pointer to  a  whole array we proceed like that:

```
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    int (*p)[3] = &arr;
```

How come i get an incompatibility error when trying to do the same with a 2D array?

```
    int arr[3][3] = {{12,10,45}, {44,55,66}, {79,85,91}};
    int (*p)[3] = &arr;
```

The problem here is &.

I'm sure this is a simple question that might have already been answered but i don't find any answer to this specific issue concerning the use of &.

Comment: On the other hand, since an array will decay to a pointer to its first element, which means that plain `arr` will be the same as `&arr[0]` which *is* of that type. So `int (*p)[3] = arr;` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, "pointer" is a *category* of types.  To get a particular type, you have to specify what type of object the pointer points *to*.

Accordingly, the unary `&` does not generically compute a pointer.  It  creates a pointer *to* the type of its operand.

Similarly, in C, "array" is a category of types.  To get a particular type, you have to specify the element type, *the number of dimensions*, and the sizes of at least the last n-1 dimensions.

Thus, with

> ```
>     int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
>     int (*p)[3] = &arr;
> ```

- `arr` is defined as an array of 3 `int`, therefore
- `&arr` has type pointer to array of 3 `int` (spelled `int (*)[3]` as a C type name), and
- `p` is declared with that type

so everything is consistent.

> How come i get an incompatibility error when trying to do the same with a 2D array?

Because your "the same" is not analogous.

With

> ```
>     int arr[3][3] = {{12,10,45}, {44,55,66}, {79,85,91}};
>     int (*p)[3] = &arr;
> ```

, `arr` has type array of 3 array of 3 `int`, and `&arr` has type pointer to array of 3 array of three `int` (a.k.a. `int (*)[3][3]`).  **This is not the same type that `p` has**.  The appropriate declaration of `p` for this version of `arr` would be

```
    int (*p)[3][3] = &arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got `p` in the second example as a pointer to a 1D array, not a pointer to a 2D array.  For that, you need the following:

```
int (*p)[3][3] = &arr;
```

Comment: that works! But how come exactly? &arr refers to the address of arr, i don't see how omitting it solves the compatibility issue.

Comment: @Talete And `int* p = arr` points to the same address as both.  The difference is the type pointed to.  `p` may refer to the same address in all three cases, but `p + 1` is very different depending on the type of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` has type `int [3][3]`, so `&arr` has type `int (*)[3][3]`.  So you can use:

```
int arr[3][3] = {{12,10,45}, {44,55,66}, {79,85,91}};
int (*p)[3][3] = &arr;
```

You can then access `p` as `(*p)[i][j]`.

But it would be more typical to use:

```
int arr[3][3] = {{12,10,45}, {44,55,66}, {79,85,91}};
int (*p)[3] = arr;
```

In this case, `int [3][3]` is compatible with an `int (*)[3]` pointer, and you can use `p[i][j]` when accessing it.

An analogous situation exists with one-dimensional arrays.  If you have `int x[3]`, then the usual pointer type to use is `int *p`, in which case you would do `p = x` and access it as `p[i]`.

But if you really want the extra level of indirection, you could use:

```
int (*p)[3] = &x;
```

Then instead of `p[i]`, you would now need to use `(*p)[i]` when accessing it.